# Koala компиляция SASS to CSS

Tags: sass

Ребят, кто подскажет. 
Не знаю что делать уже. Ситуация в следующем...
Есть проект, используется sass (в процессе изучения). 
Есть компилятор Koala, вроде все было хорошо , но перестал компилировать, только принудительно, т.е. когда я нажимаю на файл .scss правой кнопкой в коале и жму "компилировать".
Схема файлов у sass следующая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**_global_container.scss** содержит импорт всех составляющих в папке:

- _left_container.scss

**_global_header.scss** содержит импорт всех составляющих в папке:

- _header.scss
- _logo.scss
- _menu.scss
- _nav.scss
- _search.scss
- _toggle.scss

---

Соответственно в style.scss находится импорт **_global_header.scss** + **_global_container.scss**

Так вот, при такой схеме не происходит автоматическая компиляция в css если я допустим вношу изменения в файл _left_container.scss. 
Что? Почему? Слишком сложная схема для коалы? Не справляется или что?
Решил так разбить на блоки попробовать, для удобства так сказать...тестирую схемы разные для себя. И вот на такой схеме затыка.
Кто знает в чем косяк для автокомпиляции?

Comment: Надо смотреть, что выводит Sass кроме результатов. Может, там предупреждения есть, а то и ошибки. Если Коала не выводит, попробуйте собрать чем-нибудь другим.

Comment: Ошибок нету, если говорить про коалу то она просто не компилирует и все, без ошибок. Если надо где-то еще смотреть, то я не знаю где) Хотел сас поставить на windows...но что-то совсем все пошло не так, на mac os проще гораздо.

Answer (score 0):

попробовал сделать только 2 файла, это header + container, запихнул в них все что было раскидано по другим , вроде компилирует.
Выходит Коала просто не тянет большое кол-во файлов для компиляции, или не тянет длинные пути?

Comment: Использую Live Sass Compiler для VSCode уже как год, никогда не было проблем с ним, попробуйте VSCode редактор мб понравится + очень много полезных расширений.

А лучше конечно настраивать компиляцию через gulp к примеру или webpack (если здоровый проект).

У меня к примеру для мелких проектов стоит это расширение.
Для средних использую gulp, чтобы не трогать статические пути которые в конфиге расширения прописаны ;)

Comment: Я раньше тоже Koalu использовал, пока не разобрался с File Watcher  в PHPStorm.